# Why does the slope of the same coefficient change when we add new variables?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, linear

There is this question that I could not really find an answer to online. Let's say that we do a simple linear regression model with y and x1, and we compute the slope of x. Then, we make a multiple linear regression model with y, x1, and x2. But now the slope of x1 changed. Why is that?

Comment: Google for "omitted variable bias."

Comment: @MatthewGunn thanks a lot! never heard of that!

Comment: A related and highly illustrative example is [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox).

Comment: This is a FAQ: see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=regression%20coefficient%20change